# How should I set up observation space in gym?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I wanted to set up a gym environment to work on my school RL project. The environment is structured as follows: an Action Space of 7, with 6 for 3D movement and 1 for placing a block at coordinates (x, y, z). A file with an array of block coordinates will be supplied for the objective. There are certain rules for placing the block. Should I include the objective array and the blocks placed previously in the observation space (both are arrays)? Or should I return the observation with all the block placed previously, along with the current position? If yes, how should I do it? My current code as follows:

```
def __init__(self):

        self.objective = np.load('objective.npy') # Load the objective from file
        self.min_x, self.max_x, self.min_y, self.max_y, self.min_z, self.max_z= objective_functions.calculate_objective_space(self.objective) # add padding to the objective space
        self.model = CompositeBlock() 
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(7)  # 7 discrete actions
        self.observation_space =  spaces.Box(
                                    low=np.array([self.min_x, self.min_y, self.min_z,0,0]),
                                    high=np.array([self.max_x, self.max_y, self.max_z,1,1]),
                                    dtype=np.int16
                                    )
        self.reset()

def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        done = False
        # Movement in 3D space
        # Clip the cursor position to stay within bounds
        if action == 0:  
            self.cur_pos[1] += 1
            self.cur_pos[1] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[1], self.min_y, self.max_y)
        elif action == 1:  
            self.cur_pos[1] -= 1
            self.cur_pos[1] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[1], self.min_y, self.max_y)
        elif action == 2:  
            self.cur_pos[0] -= 1
            self.cur_pos[0] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[0], self.min_x, self.max_x)
        elif action == 3:  
            self.cur_pos[0] += 1
            self.cur_pos[0] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[0], self.min_x, self.max_x)
        elif action == 4:  
            self.cur_pos[2] += 1
            self.cur_pos[2] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[2], self.min_z, self.max_z)
        elif action == 5:  
            self.cur_pos[2] -= 1
            self.cur_pos[2] = np.clip(self.cur_pos[2], self.min_z, self.max_z)
        
        # Check if block placement is valid
        if action == 6:  # Place block
            if building_rules(self.cur_pos, self.model.blocks): # Check if block placement is valid
                self.model.add_block(self.cur_pos)
                if(np.any([np.array_equal(self.cur_pos, arr) for arr in self.objective])): # Reward if block placement is objective
                    reward = 1  
                else:   # Penalize if block placement is not objective
                    reward = -0.1

        done = set(map(tuple, self.objective)).issubset(set(map(tuple, self.model.blocks))) # Check if all objective blocks are placed
        self.observation = np.array(self.cur_pos)
        return self.observation, reward, done, {}
    
    def _get_info(self):
        pass
    
    def reset(self,seed = None):
        # We need the following line to seed self.np_random
        super().reset(seed=seed)

        # Reset the agent location to (0,0,0)
        self.model = CompositeBlock() 
        self.cur_pos= np.array([0, 0, 0])
        self.observation = np.array(self.cur_pos)
        
        return self.observation

    def render(self):
        # Render the environment (optional for Gym)
        pass
```

`

I will need to train a model afterwards, which should be the best option for simplicity? Currently, my observation is an array with 5 elements consisting of the current position's x, y, and z coordinates, is_placed_before (0 or 1), and is_objective_block (0 or 1). I feel like the agent does not know where the objective blocks are. I wonder how to fit the objective blocks into the observation.

Comment: I think the main point of OpenAI gym is that they already pre-defined environments (e.g. CartPole) that you can just import. Maybe they have some functions to create your environment.

For the objective array, you should definitely put it in the observation space. In each step your model has to know where to build blocks which should be a given for each step, therefore it only makes sense to put it in the observation space. I think for simplicity it is also better if you put the already placed blocks in the observation space, it'd make sense. 
But put together the observation space cleverly